# Magento 2: How to add custom filters in Orders Report?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, reports

I have added new checkbox called "Split by Country" as a filter in Orders Report section.

File:

> vendor/magento/module-reports/Block/Adminhtml/Filter/Form.php

```
$fieldset->addField(
        'split_by_country',
        'checkbox',
        [
            'label' => __('Split by Country'),
            'name' => 'split_by_country',
            'data-form-part' => $this->getData('target_form'),
            'onchange' => 'this.value = this.checked;'
        ]
    );
```

[image]

Then I added a new column in grid called "Country".

[image]

File:

> vendor/magento/module-reports/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Sales/Grid.php

```
$this->addColumn(
        'country',
        [
            'header' => __('Country'),
            'type' => 'string',
            'index' => 'country',
            'sortable' => false
        ]
    );
```

What I want to achieve here is, when a "Split by Country" checkbox is checked then in a grid I want to display entries order by country.

Please suggest me a solution for this.

Thank you

Comment: hi have you found any solution?

Comment: @Hiren, you got any solution for this?

Comment: @Hiren, please update me if you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

First of all it's very bad practice to change core code. Do not write directly in core files.

To create custom field and custom collection. you need to do following things:

Step 1) Override Order.php with your custom module file by writing as following in etc/adminhtml/di.xml file.

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Report\Filter\Form\Order" type="<PackageName>\<ModuleName>\Block\Adminhtml\Report\Filter\Form\Order" />
```

Step 2) Copy **vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Report/Filter/Form/Order.php** file in your module under directory **Block\Adminhtml\Report\Filter\Form**

Step 3) Override Grid.php by writing following in etc/adminhtml/di.xml file.

```
<preference for="Magento\Reports\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Sales\Grid" type="<PackageName>\<ModuleName>\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Sales\Grid" />
```

Step 4) Copy file **vendor/magento/module-reports/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Sales/Grid.php** in your module under directory Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Sales.

Step 5) Override function _prepareCollection() to write your own custom logic in Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Sales\Grid.php file. Checkout vendor/magento/module-reports/Block/Adminhtml/Grid/AbstractGrid.php file for more information about this function.

File : **vendor/magento/module-reports/Block/Adminhtml/Filter/Form.php**
This is the common block for all report which render common filter across all reports. To override order filter you need to override block **vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Report/Filter/Form/Order.php**. You can see layout file **vendor/magento/module-reports/view/adminhtml/layout/reports_report_sales_sales.xml** to check which block getting rendered on page.